# Add newline to regex expression (?=^.{0,50}$)

Tags: html, regex, zurb-foundation

I have this regex expression which basically only allows the user to enter 50 chars if anything more then shows an error. I have used this on a textarea so I was wondering how I could integrate newlines to also be allowed within the expression.

The expression I currently have is below,

(?=^.{0,50}$)

I am currently using Foundation abide and have added this as a pattern to the field.

Comment: Regex differ in different programming-languages. Which one do you use?

Comment: Can't you just check the length of the field text area directly? Why regex?

Comment: Im using foundation abide, and I have added this as a pattern in order to allow inline error detection. I have updated the question to include the @Johannes Reuter

Comment: I just assume the language you are using is javascript...

Comment: There is maxlength attribute on [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) tag from HTML5

Comment: Yup, its JavaScript. 

Also I have included the maxLength attr, but this is a fail safe.

Comment: A regex in your clientside business-logic is also a fail safe - you can never trust the client. If you want to do validations, do them server-side, everything else is just convenience for the client.

Comment: I do validate on the client side as well, but this is just to show the inline error messages to make sure the form does not submit (given that the rules have not been removed). But even if they are removed and submitted the form fails and returns an error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html
the dot-operator doesn't match all characters as one would expect. To also match metacharacters as newline, you have to use `[\s\S]` instead.

For your purpose, the comments that suggest just checking the length directly or applying a maxlength-attribute are much more practical, but maybe someone else will need this functionality.

Comment: Also thank you for the answer works like a charm. :) Cheers

Comment: Note that simple regex approach like this can't handle the length of astral Unicode characters correctly. Astral characters counts as 2 in JavaScript (since it requires surrogate pairs), but they should be counted as one character.